# How can I match a pattern which is not containg any capital letter in Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I have tried to match a string which is not contain any capital letter.But I don't Know how to do it. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It is unlikely that you will receive much help without putting forth any effort. There are many good regular expression tutorials online. For Perl, [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) is probably the best resource. I would take a look at that.

Comment: You want a regex to match a string not containing any capital letters?

Comment: Make sure you don't have the `ignore case` modifier turned on when you attempt your match!

Comment: I have tried this one

Answer (score 2):

Compare a lower cased version of the string to what the user entered. If they're equal, it's all in lowercase.